# Use of Let vs allow

Tags: word-choice, let

I am sorry if this is off-topic but I have searched for it on google and on [Learners Dictionary](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/let#), but couldn't find a satisfactory answer. So, I'm posting it here.

This is a question ([see image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vExDWDp0TVp9Kl_N589RpdJxUYvC29aE/view?usp=drivesdk)) on my test.

> I requested the teacher (to go out) early.
>
> - to allow me to leave
> - to let me go.

And answer is the 1st option. Can any one tell me why we reject the 2nd option.

Which one is grammatically correct?

---

Note: And if you think that *request* doesn't take *to* after it, see following examples:

Direct: He said, ‘Let me go.’
Indirect: He requested to let him go.

Direct: The boy said to his father, ‘Let me play now.’
Indirect: The boy requested his father to let him play then [(Reference)](https://www.englishpractice.com/improve/reporting-imperative-sentence-beginning/)

Comment: The test seems all wrong to me.  Mainly, this is because request used like that cannot be followed by to. If you "request the teacher to leave", your are the principal or director of the school. Sorry, but really, this is basic grammar gone wrong (in your test). Also, questions on "correct answers" are not really acceptable though I do understand this is trick since the question is faulty. I could work that into an answer if others do not wish to close this question...

Comment: @Lambie It is question of my test and I have written it as it was.

Comment: I understand that. Nevertheless, it is about choice of two, both of which are wrong because the main clause is wrong here for those. If this question is accepted by others as valid, I will answer. Let's wait and see.

Comment: @Lambie Can it be "I requested the teacher let me go early."

Comment: @Lambie But here is a few examples where request is used with to. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/request

Comment: Here is the example from that dictionary: the letter requested him to report to London. That is like: The director requested the teacher to [do something]. **You** cannot request the teacher to leave early. Is that understandable now? The question in your test would not work with "I request" and you as a student.

Answer (score 3):

While both have the same meaning, *let* is the less formal of the two (also *permit*, which is considered more formal than *allow*). The big difference: the verb that comes after *let* does not require *to* to precede it. The verb that comes after *allow* requires *to* before the verb. Note the following, the 3rd example is the one I typically use:

*I asked the teacher to let me leave early.*

*I asked the teacher to allow me to leave early.*

*I asked the teacher if I could leave early.*

Comment: +1 Thank you for that.

Comment: Instead of 'leave' can we use 'go'

Comment: @Pradeep yes, "go" is acceptable, also "take off" as in "I asked the teacher if I could take off early today".